# Core Data Relationships, NSPredicates and the NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This has been driving me nuts all day.

I have a weird bug that I think I have narrowed down to an NSPredicate. I have two entities: List and Person. List has a to-many relationship to Person called persons and Person has a to-many relationship to List called lists.

I pass to my a tableview controller a List object. I then want that tableview controller to display the Persons that belong to that list object. I am doing this with a NSFetchedResultsController.

When setting up the NSFRC, I have the following code (memory management omitted for clarity). The List in question is `myList`:

```
// Create the request and set it's entity
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Create a predicate to get the persons that belong to this list
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY lists == %@)", myList];

// Assign this predicate to the fetch request
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Define some descriptors
NSSortDescriptor *locationDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"location" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:locationDescriptor, lastNameDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"location" cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

I think the problem is with this line (because it disappears if I remove it):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY lists == %@)", myList];
```

What is happening is when the parent view passes `myList` to the tableview controller, the simulator just hangs. No crash log in the console or anything. It's almost as if it's just taking AGES to sort out the NSFRC.

Is this a problem with the predicate I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions re: using an NSSet. After hours of bug-tracking I realised that the problem lie in my cellForIndexPath method of the table view (so, unrelated to the NSFRC).

Answer (score 1):

Do you you need to use `NSFetchedResultsController` when you can obtain the `Person`s from the list passed into the tableViewController?

```
NSSet *people = myList.persons;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you can just use `myList.persons`, an `NSFetchedResultsController` is not necessary in this situation.

Comment: your comment is confusing. my answer provides an alternative which requires re-design of the tableViewController.